# Inserting array to "replace" function but it inserts the array in different order

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript function that does a couple of things:

1. gets the selected values from different select forms and adds them to an array. This works ok since it stores the values in the correct order.
2. I have const that is actually an HTML template where I need to insert the selected values in the order of the array. This is where I have my problem.
   When I insert the array it seems that it inserts the values randomly and I don't know how to fix it.

This is my js function

```
function cambiarImagen(){
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('custom-select img');
    var seleccionPath = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        var element = elements[i];
        var strSel = element.options[element.selectedIndex].text;
        seleccionPath.push(strSel);
    } console.log(seleccionPath);




    let index = 0;

    const html = `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Escenario Virtual de Imagenes</title>



    <script src="js/aframe.min.js"></script>
     <script>


//variables de estimulos dentro del arreglo de secuencias//
        var neutro='img/negro.png';
        var instruccionesImagenes='img/Imagenes_instrucciones.png';
        var imagen1='img/1.jpg'; 
        var imagen2='img/2.jpg';
        var imagen3='img/3.jpg';
        var imagen4='img/4.jpg';
        var imagen5='img/5.jpg';



</script>
</head>
<body>


</body>
</html>`;

    let result = html;

    const re = /var imagen.*='(.*)';/gm;

    while ((m = re.exec(html)) !== null) {
        result = result.replace(m[1], seleccionPath[index]);
        index++;
    }

    console.log(result);
}
```

The problem must be in the while loop because the array shows in the correct order when I console.log the array before I send it to the function.

I'll show one example of my outputs.

Array before using the while loop:

```
Array(5) [ "img/2.jpg", "img/5.jpg", "img/4.jpg", "img/1.jpg", "img/3.jpg" ]
```

The output of the replace:

```
    var imagen1='img/3.jpg'; 
    var imagen2='img/2.jpg';
    var imagen3='img/1.jpg';
    var imagen4='img/4.jpg';
    var imagen5='img/5.jpg';
```

Comment: Well, you always run a risk when you assign a variable in a condition... You should consider calling `replace` once, and [use a function as the second parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is to replace the `while` loop by a call to `String.replace()` with a function as parameter:

```js
    result = result.replace(re, (m, p1) => {
      return m.replace(m, seleccionPath[index++]);
    });
```

The function is called for each match in the order they are found. For each one, the contents of the first capture group (`p1`, which contains `'img/n.jpg'`) is replaced by whatever's in `seleccionPath` at the current index.

```js
function cambiarImagen() {
    const elements = document.getElementsByClassName('custom-select img');
    let seleccionPath = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        const element = elements[i];
        const strSel = element.options[element.selectedIndex].text;
        seleccionPath.push(strSel);
    }
    
    console.log(seleccionPath);

    let index = 0;

    const html = `
      ...
      let imagen1='img/1.jpg'; 
      let imagen2='img/2.jpg';
      let imagen3='img/3.jpg';
      let imagen4='img/4.jpg';
      let imagen5='img/5.jpg';
      ...
    `;
    
    let result = html;

    const re = /let imagen.*='(.*)';/gm;

    result = result.replace(re, (m, p1) => {
      return m.replace(p1, seleccionPath[index++]);
    });

    console.log(result);
}

cambiarImagen();
```

```html
<select class="custom-select img">
  <option>img/2.jpg</option>
</select>
<select class="custom-select img">
  <option>img/5.jpg</option>
</select>
<select class="custom-select img">
  <option>img/4.jpg</option>
</select>
<select class="custom-select img">
  <option>img/1.jpg</option>
</select>
<select class="custom-select img">
  <option>img/3.jpg</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
result = result.replace(m[1], seleccionPath[index]);
```

The problem lies in the fact that we are naively replacing the regex result substring and not considering whether it may exist more than once in `result`.

For the specific replacements and the HTML we are using, `[ "img/2.jpg", "img/5.jpg", "img/4.jpg", "img/1.jpg", "img/3.jpg" ]`, after one loop, we end up with:

```js
var imagen1='img/2.jpg'; 
var imagen2='img/2.jpg';
var imagen3='img/3.jpg';
var imagen4='img/4.jpg';
var imagen5='img/5.jpg';
```

Here we can see that "img/2.jpg" now exists twice in `result`, thus the next replacement ("img/2.jpg" with "img/5.jpg") occurs on the first line because for  [`String.prototype.replace` only the first occurence will be replaced](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace), resulting in:

```js
var imagen1='img/5.jpg'; 
var imagen2='img/2.jpg';
var imagen3='img/3.jpg';
var imagen4='img/4.jpg';
var imagen5='img/5.jpg';
```

This happens a number of times with this data set, 4 ends up in the right place (3rd slot) but then is replaced by 1 (which is supposed to end up where 4 is originally), essentially we are not taking into consideration that the matches to the regex may be inserted into the result.

Comment: As suggested elsewhere, you can call `replace` with a function parameter:
`html = html.replace(/var imagen.*='(.*)';/gm, (match, p1) => match.replace(p1, seleccionPath[index++]));`, which prevents the new filenames from becoming matches since we no longer call `replace` for each original match

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this line of code:

```
function cambiarImagen(){
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('custom-select img');
var seleccionPath = [];

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    var element = elements[i];
    var strSel = element.options[element.selectedIndex].text;
    seleccionPath.push(strSel);
} console.log(seleccionPath);

// changses begin from here
var index = 1;
var html = `<html>
<head>
<title>Escenario Virtual de Imagenes</title>
<script src='js/aframe.min.js'></script>
 <script> 
  //variables de estimulos dentro del arreglo de secuencias//
 var neutro='img/negro.png';
 var instruccionesImagenes='img/Imagenes_instrucciones.png';<br />`;

for (var i = 0; i < seleccionPath.length; i++) {
    html = html + "var imagen" + index + "='" + seleccionPath[i] + "';<br />";
    index++;
}
html += `
</script >
</head >
<body></body>
</html >`;
let result = html;
console.log(result);
}
```

the output in the html is:

```
var imagen1='img/2.jpg';
var imagen2='img/5.jpg';
var imagen3='img/4.jpg';
var imagen4='img/1.jpg';
var imagen5='img/3.jpg';
```

good luck.